# Remove comments from large files using Java

Tags: java

I have .sh, .txt, .sql, .pkb etc files with file size greater than 10 MBs which means more than 100k lines.

I want to remove comments from these file and then use the uncommented content further. I have written the following code for it.

```
/**
 * Removes all the commented part from the file content as well as returns a
 * file structure which have just lines with declaration syntax for eg.
 * Create Package packageName <- Stores all decalartion lines as separate
 * string in an array
 * 
 * @param file
 * @return file content
 * @throws IOException
 */
private static String[] filterContent(File file) throws IOException {

    String withoutComment = "";
    String declare = "";
    String[] content;
    List<String> readLines = FileUtils.readLines(file);

    int size = readLines.size();
    System.out.println(file.getName() + " Files number of lines "+ size + " at "+new Date());
    String[] declareLines = new String[size];
    int startComment = 0;
    int endComment = 0;
    Boolean check = false;
    int j = 0;
    int i=0;
    // Reading content line by line
    for (String line:readLines) {
        // If line contains */ that means comment is ending in this line,
        // making a note of the line number
        if (line.toString().contains("*/")) {
            endComment = i;
            // Removing the content before */ from the line
            int indexOf = line.indexOf("*/");
            line = line.replace(line.substring(0, indexOf + 2), "");
        }

        // If startComment is assigned fresh value and end comment hasn't,
        // that means the current line is part of the comment
        // Ignoring the line in this case and moving on to the next one
        if ((startComment > 0 && endComment == 0) || (endComment < startComment) || check)
            continue;

        // If line contains /* that means comment is starting in this line,
        // making a note of the line number
        if (line.contains("/*")) {
            startComment = i;
            // Removing the content after /* from the line
            int indexOf = line.indexOf("/*");
            line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
            if (i == 0)
                check = true; // means comment in the very first line
        }

        // If line contains -- that means single line comment is present in
        // this line,
        // removing the content after --
        if (line.contains("--")) {
            int indexOf = line.indexOf("--");
            line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
        }
        // If line contains -- that means single line comment is present in
        // this line,
        // removing the content after --
        if (line.contains("#")) {
            int indexOf = line.indexOf("#");
            line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
        }

        // At this point, all commented part is removed from the line, hence
        // appending it to the final content
        if (!line.isEmpty())
            withoutComment = withoutComment + line + " \n";
        // If line contains CREATE its a declaration line, holding it
        // separately in the array
        if (line.toUpperCase().contains(("CREATE"))) {
            // If next line does not contains Create and the current line is
            // the not the last line,
            // then considering two consecutive lines as declaration line,
            if (i < size - 1 && !readLines.get(i + 1).toString().toUpperCase().contains(("CREATE"))) {
                declare = line + " " + readLines.get(i + 1).toString() + "\n";
            } else if (i < size) {// If the line is last line, including
                                    // that line alone.
                declare = line + "\n";
            }

            declareLines[j] = declare.toUpperCase();
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Read lines "+ new Date());
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(declareLines));
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

    content = list.toArray(new String[list.size() + 1]);

    withoutComment = withoutComment.toUpperCase();
    content[j] = withoutComment;
    System.out.println("Retruning uncommented content "+ new Date());
    return content;
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] content = filterContent(new File("abc.txt"));
}
```

The problem with this code is its too slow if the file size is huge. For a 10 MB file it take more than 6 hours to remove comments. (Code ran on SSH server).

I can have files with size up to 100  MBs also, in which it takes days to remove comments. How can I remove comments faster?

**Update** : The question is not a duplicate as my problem is not just solved by changing way to read lines. Its the string activity making the process slow and I need a way to make the comment removal activities faster.

Comment: 1. Don't keep the whole file in memory. 2. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: First, don't put it into a List, use a InputStream to read the file and analyse the line directly. You can easily find if a line contain `/*` or  `/* ... */`, remove this and recreating the new file without the comment. Reading a file of more than 100MB should never took that long ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the biggest problem of my code was use of `Strings`. Reading lines by any method din't make much of a difference but using `StringBuilder` instead of `String` to store the uncommented line, changed the performance drastically. Now the same code with `StringBuilder` takes seconds to remove comments where it took hours earlier.

Here's the code. For better performance I've changed `List` to `BufferedReader`.

```
/**
     * Removes all the commented part from the file content as well as returns a
     * file structure which have just lines with declaration syntax for eg.
     * Create Package packageName <- Stores all decalartion lines as separate
     * string in an array
     * 
     * @param file
     * @return file content
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static List<String> filterContent(File file) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder withoutComment = new StringBuilder();
//      String declare = "";
//      String[] content;
//      List<String> readLines = FileUtils.readLines(file);
//
//      int size = readLines.size();
        System.out.println(file.getName() + "  at " + new Date());
        List<String> declareLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        // String line = null;
        int startComment = 0;
        int endComment = 0;
        Boolean check = false;
        Boolean isLineDeclaration = false;

        int j = 0;
        int i = 0;

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        // Reading content line by line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // line = readLines.get(i).toString();// storing current line data
            // If line contains */ that means comment is ending in this line,
            // making a note of the line number
            if (line.toString().contains("*/")) {
                endComment = i;
                // Removing the content before */ from the line
                int indexOf = line.indexOf("*/");
                line = line.replace(line.substring(0, indexOf + 2), "");
            }

            // If startComment is assigned fresh value and end comment hasn't,
            // that means the current line is part of the comment
            // Ignoring the line in this case and moving on to the next one
            if ((startComment > 0 && endComment == 0) || (endComment < startComment) || check)
                continue;

            // If line contains /* that means comment is starting in this line,
            // making a note of the line number
            if (line.contains("/*")) {
                startComment = i;
                // Removing the content after /* from the line
                int indexOf = line.indexOf("/*");
                line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
                if (i == 0)
                    check = true; // means comment in the very first line
            }

            // If line contains -- that means single line comment is present in
            // this line,
            // removing the content after --
            if (line.contains("--")) {
                int indexOf = line.indexOf("--");
                line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
            }
            // If line contains -- that means single line comment is present in
            // this line,
            // removing the content after --
            if (line.contains("#")) {
                int indexOf = line.indexOf("#");
                line = line.replace(line.substring(indexOf), "");
            }

            // At this point, all commented part is removed from the line, hence
            // appending it to the final content
            if (!line.isEmpty())
                withoutComment.append(line).append(" \n");
            // If line contains CREATE its a declaration line, holding it
            // separately in the array
            if (line.toUpperCase().contains(("CREATE"))) {
                // If next line does not contains Create and the current line is
                // the not the last line,
                // then considering two consecutive lines as declaration line,
                declareLines.add(line.toUpperCase());

                isLineDeclaration = true;
                j++;
            } else if (isLineDeclaration && !line.toUpperCase().contains(("CREATE"))) {
                // If next line does not contains Create and the current line is
                // the not the last line,
                // then considering two consecutive lines as declaration line,
                declareLines.set(j - 1, declareLines.get(j - 1) + " " + line.toUpperCase());
                isLineDeclaration = false;
            }
            i++;
        }

        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Read lines " + new Date());
//      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(declareLines));
        declareLines.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

//      content = list.toArray(new String[list.size() + 1]);

//      withoutComment = withoutComment..toUpperCase();
        declareLines.add(withoutComment.toString().toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("Retruning uncommented content " + new Date());
        return declareLines;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create several threads that do the work (proper splitting of your lines is required)

Comment: The file may even have 50 lakhs lines. Won't Creating hundreds of threads overload the thread stack?

Answer (score 0):

Some idea to get this code faster

Use an `InputStream` to read the file and analyse the line directly, store the new String in the uncommented file. This will prevent the multiple reading of the file (once to create the `List<String> readLines`, once done by your iteration)

Design, you could use a mapping for the comments syntax instead of this redondant code.

Once this would be done, this should be way faster. Off course, multithread could be a solution but this would required some check to be sure you don't split the file just in a comment block. So, first improve the code, then you could think of this.